# Is it possible and legal to burn DVD-games with the Xbox 360 to have self as a save-original-copy?

Tags: burning, xbox360, copyright

Can you burn an own copy of games for the xbox 360 console to have for yourself to save your original disk like with os and office dvds?

Comment: No, it is not legal in any way, shape, or form

Comment: That is highly dependent on where you live.

Answer (score 1):

They won't play unless your console is "modded", which is a big no-no (voids the warranty, and I think MS recently kicked out modded consoles from XBox Live.)

Answer (score 0):

No and yes.

First the No - You can't do this as the disks are not just normal DVDs, they have some sort of security/DRM built in that can detect if it is an original disk or not.

Now the yes - It is possible to mod your console to ignore if the disk is copied and this should work - however, I would not recommend this at all.

Comment: Ok, but how does that security/DRM stuff work?